# After updating the title and meta description, how long until changes take place on Google?

Tags: seo, google, title, meta-description

I am using the Yoast plugin to help with the SEO of my site. I just set everything up and am wondering how long it takes for google to update the information. As you can probably tell already the only knowledge I have is basic CSS.

What I am mainly concerned about is getting my homepage listed with the correct SEO title and meta description. Currently, my homepage is listed but not with the updated SEO title or meta description.

Comment: It takes as long as it takes. [insert friendly sarcastic grin here] It all depends upon how fresh your page/site is, how popular, how trendy, etc. It can take minutes to months. You can easily update the page for yourself by using Google Search Console Fetch as Google and Submit to Index. Even then, it can take 1-2 days to update, however, at least you know it would be sooner than later. Cheers!!

Comment: I usually see meta data refreshed the sometime over the second weekend after I've made the change.

Answer (score 8):

If you go to Google Search Console website, click on Crawl, the Fetch as Google you can order the page on your website that you are updating to be indexed.  From that point, as of the date of this writing, it has been taking between one and 16 days for Google to carry out the indexing.  This is based on about 60 pages that I have been modifying during the last three months.

However, the new headline of the Google entry from the title tag (sometimes erroneously called the page title, which is from the h1 title tag and appears at the top of the page text) sometimes appears before the indexing date that shows up on Google cache copy.  Apparently, this happens after the page is crawled and copied, but before it is indexed.

Comment: To speed up indexing, this is the method I use to request indexing. It gets updated as soon as possible.

Comment: FYI, you have to start by clicking on "Go To the Older Version" at the bottom of the menu on the left-hand side - the newer version of Search Console doesn't have "Crawl" readily available anywhere. *EDIT* -  and then you'll see that the report is no longer available and you have to use the new URL Inspection Tool in the New Search Console! Enter the URL in the URL Inspection Tool and then hit REQUEST INDEXING.

Answer (score 4):

There is no definite answer on how long will google take to reflect your content.

But primarily it depends on few important factors like:

1. How often google crawls this page of your site which again depends on lot of factors, most important of which is content refresh rate.
2. Depends if you are linking this page to a already indexed page or submitting this via sitemap etc

But to ensure this gets crawled fast, you should submit your page via Google Search Console: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

Answer (score 1):

Automatically these changes can be accepted from a day to a week.

Factors that could delay this are as below:

Crawl budget - exhausted by crawling unnecessary pages

- Sitemap - change frequency, last mod
- Internal linking - lack of internal linking
- Backlinks - lack of external links
- Meta Robots - forgot to remove, or change the attributes
- robots.txt - some rules may be blocking your content, check your pages with old Google Webmaster's [robots.txt Checker](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) Tool - under Crawl section

Tips to get indexed faster:

- Update you sitemap and add lastmod and change frequency attributes appropriately.
  _ Internal link that page to your popular pages, in a natural way, don't be messy.
- Get backlinks from good websites, use ping sites.

These are some of the ways you can try manually or wait for Google to do it for you in next crawl.

Answer (score 0):

If your site's content is unique and catchy then it may takes 1 or 2 days. sometimes it may take longer than a week, it's important to fetch that URL through webmaster tools after making any updates or changes.

Comment: Can you explain more? For example, how to perform the steps you are recommending. Cheers!!

Comment: To push your updated page on google to crawl you have to go google webmaster tools now known as search console. At left sidebar click on crawl pages an then click on fetch as google, now you can put link followed by home page and then click on fetch you can fetch as render or fetch this url only, if you want updated only that url then choose this url only and submit. it will take some hours or a day to index in google.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer? The reason why I made a comment is because the system triggered a "low quality post" flag for the answer. I left a comment to help. Thanks! Cheers!!